# Palindrome iterative checker

Tags: java

```
package Checkers;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class iterative 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
   String reverseString="";
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   String more = null;
   do {
   System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome:");
   String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
   String combined = inputString.replaceAll("[\\W]", "");
   combined = combined.toLowerCase();

   int length = combined.length();

   for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
   reverseString = reverseString + combined.charAt(i);

   if (combined.equals(reverseString))
   System.out.println("Input string is a palindrome.");
   else
   System.out.println("Input string is not a palindrome.");
   // Ask user to Evaluate another string
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Evaluate another string? (Y=Yes): ");
    more = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
   }    
   while (more.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
}

}
```

Output: Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome:
radar
Input string is a palindrome.

Evaluate another string? (Y=Yes): y

Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome:
radar
Input string is not a palindrome.

Evaluate another string? (Y=Yes):

I have this problem when I put a palindrome in like for example radar. Its a palindrome. put it in again and i get its not a palindrome. I don't whats wrong please help

Comment: reverseString isn't reset to check the second input.

Comment: because `reverseString ` is outside your loop and you dont reset it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the line

```
String reverseString="";
```

into

```
do { ...}
```